# HTTP server with socket communication

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am trying to create a simple http server, that will take http requests from a client and interact with an application that listens on a port (on the same host).

My initial take on that was to create a BaseHTTPServer with custom definitions of GET,POST.

So when a request arrived on the server, the custom POST method would first create a socket for the communication with the underlying application. It then extract the data that needs to be passed to that application and write them through the socket. Then when the application to respond and pass that response to the response of the initial post request.

Even though that flow works at a degree, i feel that there is a much more appropriate solution to the problem.

in a nutshell, we have:

**Server:**

> appA running on port 8000
>
> http server on port 80

**Client:**

> connect to http server and interact with appA through http requests.
>   e.g. post for sending data, get to receive response

Any thoughts on how to solve the problem more appropriately?

Maybe a library to handle sockets at a higher level (currently I am connecting to the socket and use select to read,write data). I think asyncio may have such capability?

In general how would somebody optimally approach that problem. (without getting in trouble of implementing stuff that are already there, like http server)

Comment: *Any thoughts on how to solve the problem more appropriately?* - there is not enough known about the problem to make useful recommendations, i.e. the question is too broad.

Comment: Indeed, i have updated the question to be more specific into what I am looking

Comment: Just a few things which are missing from your question but which have lots of impact how you design such a system: performance requirements, concurrency requirements, amount of data exchange, any kind of authentication or authorization, caching ....

Comment: I am currently looking into the simplest case, to have a working design with a single thread, no caching and no authentication/authorization. It's on an abstract level

Comment: If you just looking to keep it simple at the beginning your current approach makes sense. Maybe you can keep the connection to the application open as an optimization but this depends on the unknown API of the application.  If the connection to the application can be made simpler (i.e. something fancier than plain sockets) again depends on the unknown API and protocol spoken with the application.